# Do the test tokens for Slack's API service run out?

Tags: python, slack-api

I'm using slackclient to connect my Python script to Slack's API so that I can write to certain channels through it.  If I hope to run this query every day and am currently using Slack's test tokens instead of a more complicated approach of using flask (suggested elsewhere online), will I run into an eventual problem?  Do the test tokens run out or have a max call number per day?

current code:

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
slack_client = SlackClient('test_token')  
slack_client.api_call("api.test")

def send_message(channel_id, message):
slack_client.api_call(
    "chat.postMessage",
    channel=channel_id,
    text=message,
    username='name',
    icon_emoji=':clap:'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rate limits](https://api.slack.com/docs/rate-limits) imposed by Slack API is common for all the available authentication modes. There is no specific max call number per day w.r.t to Test Tokens. And there is no expiration set for the Test Tokens.

Comment: Thanks @franklinsijo